# Firebase Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm new to Firebase and really struggling with the security rules.

I'm trying to store data for anonymous user sessions that can only be accessed by that user but as soon as I tighten up the security rules I get permission denied and can't work out why.

The structure I have is:

/userSessions/$user/user_id

The application pushes to user sessions and writes the user_id as returned by the anonymous login.

I have the following security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "userSessions": {
      "$user": {
        ".write": "newData.child('user_id').val() == auth.id",
        "user_id": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but can't work out how to use the security simulator either so don't know how to go about troubleshooting this

Any help greatly appreciated

EDIT -
Problem occurs when trying to create a new entry under userSessions after authenticating anonymously.

Code:

```
var userSessionsRef = new Firebase('https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/userSessions');
var userSession;
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin( userSessionsRef, function(error,user) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
        userSessionsRef.child(user.id).set({
            user_id: user.id,
            provider: user.provider,
            created: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            });
    userSession = new Firebase('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/userSessions/'+user.id);
    userSession.onDisconnect().remove();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when you get permission denied?

Comment: Create a new $user under userSessions - I'll update the question

Comment: Hi @JonReeves! What do you get when you try this out in simulator? Also, it seems likely that user.id is a number (I assume you're using Twitter or Facebook? They both return numeric ids). Also, what data is getting set? Can you log the user object and post that here? There's a lot more data you can offer us that will make troubleshooting painless and quick.

Comment: I can't actually use the simulator - it just says uh oh. Something went wrong...

Comment: I am using anonymous authentication which returns a string for ID, and all I am setting at the moment is the data returned from the authentication and a timestamp (as in the code above) just to keep things simple

Comment: @JonReeves please shoot an email over to support@firebase.com regarding simulator. Please include any errors in the JavaScript console, browser name/version, and any other details you can get us to help reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set() operation you've provided runs great; no errors; there must be another issue at play here that you haven't captured in your repro (did you enable anonymous auth in Forge?). Here's a fiddle running on your security rules, copied line-for-line (just moved down one child path): http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/wxn5J/

On a related note, your current security rules will not allow the `userSession.onDisconnect().remove();` op, since records can only be written if newData() contains a user_id value (i.e. it can't be null). A better way to structure these security rules would be as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "userSessions": {
      "$user": {
        ".write": "$user === auth.id", // delete allowed
        "user_id": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val() === $user"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Tried those rules and still get permission denied.  Have definitely got Anonymous auth enabled in Forge.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.  On the plus side, the simulator is now working but I'm not sure how to use this to test the anonymous auth as it doesn't give me the user id so I have no way of testing a write with it?

Comment: Using your code as well against my firebase works - must have had something wrong in there somewhere.  Many thanks for your help